# Batch forecasting in R at depot level

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Need help from **R** users. I have sales data at depot level in following form in excel:SalesData.csv where Jan-2014 , Feb-2014 etc. shows sales volume in respective month of particular item in particular depot. There are multiple items in multiple depots.

**|Depot |Item |Jan-2014 |Feb-2014 |Mar-2014 |............ |Oct-2016|**

I want to predict the sales forecast for Nov-16, Dec-16 and Jan-17. There are around 1600 Depot/ Item combination so its difficult to do forecasting one by one.

Can anyone help with how to apply Batch Forecasting technique in R using above data to predict Forecast?

Comment: That sounds like a job for the hts package in R.

Comment: Hi Sir! Thanks for the response. I have gone through lot of blogs but unable to find any demo or tutorial on how to use  hts package from the scratch(raw data to forecast). Can you kindly let me know how can I find a demo/tutorial to learn about this package. PS: I am new to R

Comment: The package has a vignette. That's usually the best place to start. It is also discussed in my online book at http://otexts.org/fpp/9/4.